# Printing out each item in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to list the items in an array list from another class.

I have 3 classes in total

Tell - The main program

Item - The class that creates individual telephone directory items

Directory - A directory object which stores all the items.

What I'm trying to do is list all the items within the array list created in "directory" and im doing it like this....

TELL

```
if (Directory.entries.size>0)
{
     for (int i=0; i<Directory.entries.size(); i++) // Check size of array
     {
           Directory.entries.get(i).showRecord();
     }
}
```

DIRECTORY

```
public void printItem()      
{
     //I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT GOES HERE
}
```

ENTRY

```
public class Entry
{
String name;
String telNo;
public Entry(String aName, String aTelNo )
{
    setNumber(aTelNo);
    setName(aName);
}
// Add methods here
private void setNumber(String aTelNo)
{
    telNo = aTelNo;
}

public String getNumber()
{
    return telNo;
}

private void setName(String aName)
{
    name = aName;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + "." + telNo;
}


}
```

However I havnt got the foggiest what needs to go in the printItem() Method to allow me to print the individual items in the directory.

Could someone point me in the right direction? This is the first time I have ever really used array lists accross multiple classes and I'm very confused.

Comment: Where are you invoking your printItem from? And what do you want to print there?

Comment: You never call printItem, so put whatever you want. Put an ASCII art picture of your cat for all the good it will do.

Comment: You do need to implement the showRecord method you're calling in Entry, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have overrided the `toString` in your `Entry` class, so what all you need to do is iterate over your List and print each item. It will automatically invoke the toString of your Entry class and print the returned value: -

Put this code in your `print` method, which is in `Directory` class.

```
public static void print() {
    for (Entry entry: Directory.entries) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

`entries` is the `static` list you have in your `Directory` class.

And from your `Tell` class, just invoke your `print` method:-

```
Directory.print();
```

Comment: Perfect, thankyou... is there anyway to count if the amount of items in Directory.entries is greater than 0 from the Tell method? 

I have tried if (Directory.entries > 0)

Comment: Do `Directory.entries.size() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you don't have a call to `printItem()`; I am assuming your call to `.showRecord()` is either going to replace `printItem()` or be removed because they are trying to accomplish the same thing.

Assuming that you remove `.showRecord()` and just use `printItem()` instead, and that you are using some type of collection with data member named `entries` inside the `Directory` class:

```
public void printItem() {
    for (Entry entry : this.entries) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

is all you need since you already overrode the `toString()` function inside your `Entry` class. This iterates through each entry in the directory for you and prints them on at a time on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeMap<String, String>` to hold the telephone directory list of items.
TreeMap will ensure that your keys are sorted in Natural order (by person name) and that there are no duplicate names in the directory (every persons name is unique ). 
To print an entry would be a simple `String treeMap.get(key);`